# How can I choose the IP sites see from me?

Tags: privacy, ip, anonymity

I'm wondering how can I change and select the IP address sites see from me so I can create multiple accounts from the same device?

Answer (score 1):

A VPN allows you to change your IP address, but sites may restrict sign ups from VPN, and many now require phone verification etc. There are many VPN providers that allow you to choose the specific geographic location of the servers being utilized, in some cases down to a city level. However, most sites won't prevent you from signing up from the same IP address. Many users could share an external IP (such as is the case at an office) or home users on a single home internet connection. It would be counter intuitive for say, Google, to stop multiple people from one IP signing up for accounts. Yourself, and others in your home likely want a gmail account. Do you have a more specific example where this is a restriction put in place?

Comment: what VPN's could make you choose same city IPs? i need it to create multiple accounts on same site where registration terms and condition doesn't permit multiple account from same IP to be created, also can you change the device a site sees it's being used from with a VPN?

Comment: I recommend you search for a VPN, there are no shortage that allow what I have stated in my previous answer but keep in mind previous users of that VPN may have used the corresponding IP for site registration and based on what you are saying that may mean the IP is blocked from creating another account. Additionally sites may block IPs they recognize as being associated with VPNs altogether.

Comment: As for 'change the device a site sees' I am not 100% if you mean hide that you are using a VPN or hide what device you are using; either way this is basic stuff which you could find with a simple google search. If this violates their terms, there is likely a reason and you should respect it unless they are paying you to test that this single registration per IP feature is working correctly (which based on your questions I doubt is the case).

Comment: That being said you could utilize VPNs or proxies, virtual machines, browser plugins that modify user-agent (likely not the best approach), incognito or private browsing modes to prevent tracking cookies from the site etc. All of this depends on how the site is tracking devices (and you haven't given details outside of stating they won't allow 2 accounts from 1 IP), deciding which IPs are allowed to register accounts, which are not, and why it dictates a single registration per IP. Either way, I recommend you do some basic networking review and in the meantime follow their terms of service.